# Merged object into Array of object with same key

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am looking to merge the object with the same key in an array of objects.

I have the first object structure like this

```
   const cultures = {
     "en-us": {
       "path": "/en/playground/copy/",
       "startItem": {
         "id": "8cd7943c-1ba5-41cb-a9ac-7435fbdb1458",
         "path": "path"
       }
     },
     "da-dk": {
       "path": "/playground/copy/",
       "startItem": {
         "id": "8cd7943c-1ba5-41cb-a9ac-7435fbdb1458",
         "path": "path"
       }
     }
   }
```

And I have the second array of object like this

```
const lang = [
      {
        name: 'English',
        isoCode: 'en-us',
        url: '/en/'
      },
      {
        name: 'Danish',
        isoCode: 'da-dk',
        url: '/'
      }
    ]
```

I want to get just the path of the first object and merged in the array of objects with same key. Would it be possible to achieve something like this?

```
[
  {
    name: 'English',
    isoCode: 'en-US',
    url: '/en/',
    path: "/en/playground/copy/",
    
  },
  {
    name: 'Danish',
    isoCode: 'da-DK',
    url: '/',
    path: "/playground/copy/",
    
  }
]
```

I tried this and returns false always.

```
languages.filter((item, i) => {
      const arr = [];
      const result = item.isoCode === data.cultures[item.isoCode];

      arr.push(result);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map new objects with new `path` property.

```js
const
    cultures = { "en-us": { path: "/en/playground/copy/", startItem: { id: "8cd7943c-1ba5-41cb-a9ac-7435fbdb1458", path:  "path" } }, "da-dk": { path: "/playground/copy/", startItem: { id: "8cd7943c-1ba5-41cb-a9ac-7435fbdb1458", path:"path" } } },
    lang = [{ name: 'English', isoCode: 'en-us', url: '/en/' }, { name: 'Danish', isoCode: 'da-dk', url: '/' }],
    result = lang.map(o => ({ ...o, path: cultures[o.isoCode].path }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That map with path did the trick. You are so great!